# How do I change the background color in an HTML document?

Tags: colors

How do I change the background color in an HTML document? I'm working on a website for a friend and need to change the background color to RGB 242,53,145 and don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

You can either do it in a CSS file or do it with a `style` tag in your body.

```
<body style="background-color:rgb(242,53,145);">
</body>
```

Another option is to define it using a `<style>` element, this would be done outside of your `body` element

```
<style>
  body{background-color:rgb(242,53,145);}
</style>
<body>
  ...
</body>
```